# How to stylize Ruby on rails devise forms

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This is my registration form which is using `devise` but for some reason, my CSS only affects the `First_Name` part and nothing else. On top of that, the First Name part looks slightly different from the other bars in terms of its border color. I did install bootstrap but I haven't had a problem like this on other pages so I don't think that's the issue.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field input">
    <%=f.label :First_Name%>
    <%=f.text_field :fname, class:"form-control",:autofocus => true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field input">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field input">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field input">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
```

```
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

<style>
.input{
  width: 25%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply `.form-control` class to input fields for appling Bootstrap style.

In your code only first name (fname) has `.form-control` - You have to add it to other input fields as well.

Example for email field:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class:"form-control" %>
```